# Does C# (.Net) differentiate between signaling and quiet NaNs?

Tags: c#, .net, nan

Does C# differentiate between signaling and quiet NaNs?

And if so, how can I invoke both and examine the properties?

Comment: I'm *fairly sure* that the answer is no, C# has only one NaN type and it is constant.

Answer (score 2):

No. I couldn't find any reference to Quiet or Signaling NaNs in the spec or the code.

The spec doesn't mention different NaN types. From [4.1.6 Floating point types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691146.aspx):

> The Not-a-Number value, often abbreviated NaN. NaN's are produced by invalid floating-point operations, such as dividing zero by zero.

A few examples from the source code:

- [`Double.NaN`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/double.cs,52):

  ```
  public const double NaN = (double)0.0 / (double)0.0;
  ```
- [`Double.IsNaN`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/double.cs,97):

  ```
  return (*(UInt64*)(&d) & 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFL) > 0x7FF0000000000000L;
  ```
- [`Math.IEEERemainder(double x, double y)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/math.cs,206):

  ```
  public static double IEEERemainder(double x, double y) {
      if (Double.IsNaN(x)) {
          return x; // IEEE 754-2008: NaN payload must be preserved
      }
      if (Double.IsNaN(y)) {
          return y; // IEEE 754-2008: NaN payload must be preserved
      }

      double regularMod = x % y;
      if (Double.IsNaN(regularMod)) {
          return Double.NaN;
      }
      // ...
  }
  ```

Comment: It is difficult to prove something doesn't exist. Here are a few places where it isn't found.